# Symfony2 Rendering a form widget form_row() (HTML5 considerations)

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to render a form widget. This is the raw HTML I want to generate:

```
<input type="email" class="input-long" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
```

Using this:

```
{{ form_row(form.email, { 'type' : 'email', 'attr' : { 'class' : 'input-long', 'placeholder': "Enter Email", 'name': "email", 'id':"email", 'required': "required"}}) }}
```

did not generated the required output (for example, the input type was "text").

How do I custom render a form widget to specify the input type, placeholder etc?

**Update**

Here is my form class:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fist_name')
            ->add('last_name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('token')
            ->add('is_validated')
            ->add('created_at')
            ->add('updated_at')
            ->add('promotion')
            ->add('refferer')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Contact',
        );
    }
}
```

`{{ form.email }}` renders this:

```
<label for="acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype_email" class=" required">Email</label><input id="acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype_email" name="acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype[email]" required="required" type="text">
```

When form built adding widget email as `add->('email','email')`

It rendered this:

```
<label for="acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype_email" class=" required">Email</label><input id="acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype_email" name="acme_contactlistbundle_contacttype[email]" required="required" type="email">
```

BUT, I don't want the label rendered (it is messing up my carefully laid out page!).

In the end, I got fed up and used this ugly piece of hackery ... (fobj is the form object passed in from the controller action):

Comment: Is your form widget set up as email? What's the output you got?

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements to form rendering are different from what Symfony2 provides, you then could define your own widget. Just extend form theme and redefine needed block:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block field_widget %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value }}" />
{% endblock field_widget %}
```

And, of course, check [documentation on form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes)

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to render only `<input>` tag without `<label>` - then you should redefine your field widget in next way:

```
{% block _contact_email_row %}
    <div>
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`_contact` is for your `Type` name.
`_email` is for field name.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the documentation yesterday. However an example (in the documentation) would have been nice - since It's still not clear to me how to generate the code I want from the snippet in the documentation (which you posted above). Can you show how to generate the code I want to generate from the form widget `form.email`, using the snippet you posted above?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I will. Please, attach listing of your builder, where you add `email` field

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Did you try to pass `type` from calling builder's `add()` method?             ->add('email', 'email')

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli also please attach how the generated field look like